# Fash-CS5 after changing movieclip size fonts/images are getting squeezed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have one movie clip of size 1280 x 720 with some images, buttons and text in it.
Run-time I need to change size of this movie clip to 1280 x 300, after doing so images, buttons and text in the movie clip gets squeezed vertically.

How do i display same move clip with images and text in it with different sizes without disturbing the size of the contains.

New edit/update:
in another case i have list inside the movie clip.
What i want to archive is i want to keep the list item size static and it should not change if parent re-sizes. if it is not possible in flash then how can i re-size all the items in the list. i don't know why list is not using scrolling property properly to display it's contains according to size. Suppose for example if list size is of 600px then it should display 7 items in list and then provide scroll for other items and if we re-size the list to suppose 300 and it should display 4 items and provide scroll for.   remaining item

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this MovieClip is the main document class set the following properties of stage:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

if this MovieClip exists elsewhere within your swf/timeline/display stack then you can override the width/height setters and write some custom code to organise your MovieClip

```
override public function set width(value:Number):void
{
    //organise your MovieClips images/buttons/text horizontally
}

override public function set height(value:Number):void
{
    //organise your MovieClips images/buttons/text vertically
}
```

There are more complex solutions (rendering changes only once, rather than on each setter call) and for those I'd look at how Keith Peters handles this in his MinimalComponents library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your solution by adding stage align and scaleMode to my document main class but has no effect. The move clip that i am resizing is added using addChild to the stage.

Comment: Then you will need to create a subclass of the MovieClip class and override its setter method for height to rearrange its content.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you've got one movie clip with an image, some text fields, and buttons on it. You are resizing the movieclip, which distorts all its sub-displayobjects.

What you want to do instead is either override the width/height setters (as Hawks suggested) or add a new method (eg. `resize( newHeight:int )`) that does something like:

```
function resize( newHeight:int ):void
{
    // resize the image
    image.height = newHeight;
    image.scaleX = image.scaleY; // this will maintain the aspect

    // re-position the other elements
    button.y = newHeight - button.height - 5; // where 5 is the margin

    textField1.y = button.y - textField1.height; // if you want the text field to be positioned above the button
}
```

Comment: What you want to do is alter the scrollRect of the parent clip (or the list container clip) within the 'resize' method.